# Odd Table Row Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

My Javascript is quite basic, but for some reason I am having trouble.  I have a table that is dynamically being built and the goal of my script is to select the last 5 rows if there are more then 10 total rows and apply a CSS style to those final five.  I built a stripped down example where the first 5 rows should be made blue and the last 5 rows made red.  http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/3zCp8/

There is probably a much better way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

**ANSWER**:
Using `slice()` allowed me to accomplish my goal.  That can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/3zCp8/  Thank you Kevin B.

Comment: Not stripped down enough, way too much noise.

Comment: I don't think there's really enough information here. Coloring the last 5 and first 5 could be done with a one-liner using `:gt` and `:lt`, though looking at your code i'm not sure if that's what you are actually going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you explained you are trying to do in your question, the simplest way to accomplish it is:

```
var rows = $("table.primary_table > tbody > tr");
if (rows.length > 10) {
    rows.filter(":lt(5)").css("background-color", "blue")
        .end()
        .slice(-5).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you very much.  I was unaware of slice(), good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code for too long I guess you're looking for the [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selectors.

Edit: since you're getting all rows anyway [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) would probably be better.